# Liaison avec « long », /lɔ̃g/ ou /lɔ̃k/ ?

Tags: phonétique, liaisons

On lit dans le *Trésor de la Langue Française* à propos de [*long*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/long) :

> Prononciation et orthographe : [lɔ̃], fém. [lɔ̃g]. [lɔ̃k] devant
>   voyelle ou h non aspiré : un long arrêt [lɔ̃karɛ], un long hiver
>   [lɔ̃nkivɛr]. Selon DUPRÉ 1972 l'usage moderne a tendance à introduire
>   [g] dans ces cas plutôt que [k].

On trouve chez Racine dans la tirade de Néron (Britannicus, acte II, scène 2) les vers suivant :

> *Immobile, saisi d'un long étonnement*,
>   *Je l'ai laissé passer dans son appartement*.

De nombreux enregistrements sont disponibles sur Youtube, on entend ces vers notamment dans :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bb3CovrC7VY à 3'05''
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQzP4QtQbR0 à 0'57''
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaMKDQCfo0Q à 0'29''
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Sd0rKhtUKU&t=1747s à 29'16''
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrjuV40DQso&t=497s à 8'15''

Le tableau est contrasté et je soupçonne que la liaison classique en /k/ est surreprésentée chez les comédiens professionnels dont on peut penser que la diction est conservatrice.  Je voudrais vous sonder pour savoir comment vous réalisez cette liaison ou pour obtenir des informations plus précises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ♦ Les mots qui se terminent par *g* dans l'écriture se lient par
>   [k] dans la langue soignée :
>  <sub>*Un long effort* [lɔ̃-kɛfɔʀ],
>   *Suer sang et eau* [sɑ̃-keo] ; — dans la *Marseillaise, sang impur* [sɑ̃-kɛ̃pyʀ], — L'usage ordinaire préfère [g] : [lɔ̃-gɛfɔʀ], ou ne
>   fait pas la liaison : [sɑ̃eo], [sɑ̃ɛ̃pyʀ].</sub>
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. De Boeck/Duculot,
>   14<sup>e</sup>, § 42 a) ]

---

> [...] La lettre *g* peut se prononcer [k] *(k)*, comme la lettre *k*;
>   plusieurs ouvrages recommandent cette prononciation, mais elle est
>   très rare aujourd'hui au Québec. On la réservera donc au style très
>   soigné. Dans le style courant, on prononcera [g] *(gu)* comme dans le
>   mot *langue* en contexte de liaison.
>   [...]
>   -  Ils ont eu un **long entretien** hier soir. [lɔ̃gɑ̃tʀətjẽ] (lon-**gan**-tre-ti-in) (langue courante) ou [lɔ̃**kɑ̃** tʀətjẽ] (lon-**kan**-tre-ti-in) (langue soutenue)
>
> [ Banque de dépannage linguistique (OQLF), [*Changements phoniques
>   dans les liaisons*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3545) ]

Je préfère la nuance au LBU14 « ...ou ne fait pas la liaison », absente de la BDL ; je commence à penser qu'avec le *g*, on fait la liaison en [g] avec l'usage soigné et pas de liaison du tout dans l'usage courant. Mais j'ai de la difficulté à déterminer si je fais la liaison dans *long hiver* ; avec, je trouve étrange (*longuivers*), sans, je trouve le hiatus long. Dans tous les cas la liaison en [k] avec *hiver* m'est stupéfiante. Un personne plus âgée que moi au Québec me dit qu'elle ne la (la liaison en [g]) fait pas avec *hiver*, mais la ferait avec *automne/été*. Avec *hiver* on dit surtout un *hiver (b[i]en) long*, et c'est la seule saison qui est toujours longue, alors qu'avec *entretien* on fait davantage précéder l'adjectif et je fais la liaison plus facilement. Peut-être que chez moi la position usuelle de l'adjectif joue sur la familiarité du son de la liaison ? Cette asymétrie me laisse perplexe.

Answer (score 2):

Contrairement à la liaison après ***D*** qui le transforme régulièrement en ***T*** (un grand homme), ou celle qui suit un ***F*** pour le transformer en ***V*** (neuf heures), la liaison qui transformait un ***G*** en ***K*** ne se fait plus dans le français d'aujourd'hui.

Seules subsistent quelques liaisons figées comme celles déjà évoquées, Bour**g**-en-Bresse, très respectée au moins dans la région et *San**g** impur* qui, au contraire, l'est de moins en moins.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr qu'il s'agisse d'une liaison à proprement parler dans le cas de Bourg-en-Bresse.  Les gens de la région disent je vais à Bourg /burk/ tout court, la prononciation du /k/ final ne dépend pas de sa liaison avec un son vocalique suivant. C'est comme si la ville s'appelait Bourque et non Bourg.

Comment: C'est vrai, mais il s'agit là d'une persistance de la prononciation médiévale du français, ou plutôt de la prononciation arpitane plus récente, mais le dévoisement procède du même phénomène linguistique

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble tout d'abord que l'on doive considérer cette pratique comme assez arbitraire; quand d'un côté on écrit « seconde » et que l'on trouve moyen de prononcer ce mot comme « segonde », comment, d'un autre, peut-on  concevoir qu'il convient de prononcer « long étonnement » comme « lonkétonnement »; personnellement, je n'ai ni une habitude de faire une liaison naturelle (longuétonnement), ni de ne pas en faire; je pourrais faire cette liaison ou ne pas la faire et je pourrais tout aussi bien l'entendre dans la bouche de quelqu'un sans trouver à redire. « Lonkétonnement » serait cependant étrange à mon oreille, il me semble n'avoir jamais entendu cette prononciation dans le parler courant, ni autrement, sauf pour la première fois dans les enregistrements proposés (théatre de Racine).

Cette liaison en k est inexistante dans la langue courante ([ref](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic36611-la-consonne-de-liaison-g.html)) ; l'opinion de quelqu'un dans la source mentionnée est que beaucoup de monde ne fait pas la liaison ou alors on la trouve dans des locutions figées ou le nom d'une ville comme « Bourg-en-Bresse » (nom auquel, d'ailleurs, je trouverais la prononciation « bourenbresse » préférable) ; par exemple, les gens ne font pas cette liaison dans « long article » et « long hiver ».

On pourra invoquer des textes traditionnels comme par exemple celui de La Marseillaise, pour lesquels la pratique de la liaison en k devrait être préservée (qu'un sang-k-impur), mais voilà une interprétation de ce chant dans lequel on peut clairement entendre qu'aucune liaison n'est faite ([ref](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=221UWotqwdo), à 52 s). Je ne me rappelle pas du tout avoir fait cette liaison du temps de ma scolarité lorsque les instituteurs nous apprenaient le chant ou nous le faisaient chanter lors des cérémonies, ni même,  plus tard, de l'avoir jamais remarquée.

En fin de compte, c'est une liaison que je trouve très peu naturelle et je crois que c'est bien dommage pour la rime de « bouc » avec « joug » mais la langue française et ses étudiants ont  tout à gagner dans une simplification qui serait de n'adopter aucune liaison ; il est extrêmement plus important de passer son temps à assimiler un vocabulaire varié qu'à accumuler de la connaissance à propos de règles de prononciation trop arbitraires et autres matières accessoires de cette sorte.

Comment: Merci de votre réponse.  Ce qui est en jeu, je crois, c'est le même phénomène que celui qu'on voit à l'œuvre dans "grand" comme dans "grand amour" /grɑ̃tamur/, grand espoir "/grɑ̃tɛspwar/", où la prononciation avec une liaison en /d/ ou sans liaison du tout me semblerait fautive dans le sens où un locuteur natif ne les prononcerait pas de la sorte.  D'accord avec vous pour l'assimilation du vocabulaire varié pour un étranger apprenant le français, mais on peut mener son apprentissage sur plusieurs fronts et les curiosités de la langue, son arbitraire, son incongru, en font aussi le charme.

Comment: Pour connaître un peu la Bresse et le Bugey, les habitants du coin quand ils parlent de Bourg-en-Bresse disent plus simplement Bourg /burk/.

Comment: @petitrien Je comprends bien que pour des cas comme « grand espoir » une question de forte habitude met un terme à pratiquement toute discussion, mais on ne sait peut être pas tout en matière de preuve scientifique ; s'il peut être prouvé qu'il n'y a pas vraiment plus de difficulté à ne pas faire ces liaison il n'y a plus en jeu qu'une question d'esthétique, et une des premières constatations que l'on peut faire sous cet angle-là est que la liaison introduit une déformation de l'un ou de l'autre des deux mots ; cela est-t-il vraiment esthétique ? (champ 1)

Comment: @petitrien Je pense que l'esthétique d'une langue est un de ses aspects importants, mais qu'il doit être pris en considération dans ses caractéristiques générales et le moins possible dans le détail plus ou moins inutile de prononciation et d'orthographe ; c'est l'enseignement de la réforme 1990 ; il est très intéressant d'avoir l'accent circonflexe sur le e de forêt pour nous rappeler que la racine contient un s et que cet accent le remplace, mais finalement ce n'est qu'une curiosité pour le spécialiste, ça n'apporte rien à la communication. (champ 2)

Comment: @petitrien Je ne parle pas que pour l'étudiant étranger, mais pour tout utilisateur de la langue ; je crois  qu'il y a beaucoup à faire avant que l'on n'ait plus à entendre de gens instruits dire des choses comme « L'orthographe est plus qu'une mauvaise habitude, c'est une vanité. » et « Il n'y a rien de plus irrationnel/bête que l'orthographe mais il faut la connaitre si on ne veut pas passer pour un ignorant. ». (fin)